# How to shrink wrap on a complex mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, object-mode, shrinkwrap

I am trying to model this character:
[image]

I have made the body and now trying to make the stripes on its body, I created a plane to act as one of the stripes:
[image]

And now want to wrap it around the character.
The problem is, instead of wrapping nicely around its lower body like in the reference.
It sticks to its arm like this:
[image]

If I try to lower the stripe it simply sticks to the leg instead:
[image]

I tried playing with the wrap method and snap mode, but didn't get better results.

How can I properly wrap the plane to make a stripe on the body like in the reference?

Comment: Hello, I don't think that this is the best method to do the stripes, you should better use an image texture

Comment: Could even make a simple shader drawing bars based on UV coordinates, adjust the bars, bake to a texture, this way the bars would be aligned to the topology nicely. Probably will work on arms better than on torso. Then you can edit that texture further in 2D/3D program, remove the bars where you don't want them, add the ⚡ etc.

Comment: Or .. extrude the stripes from the original mesh, if you want a slight profile, and use another material on those faces

Comment: @Robin Betts Yes that's the other solution (except the lightning makes it a bit tedious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Instead of doing it with a flat line try using cylinders without the end caps.
You can cut them with a boolean or manually separate them into 2 to make those symmetrical lines.

Otherwise you could also manually draw the lines on the surface in the same way that you do retopology (there are many tutorial on youtube for this) but bending a straight line around a cylinder is more complicated than it needs to be for this purpouse.